# Error en migracion en c#

Tags: mysql, c#

por favor alguien que me ayude!! al momento de hacer update-database me aparece esto Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Activo' to data type bit.
The statement has been terminated. y e cambiado los tipo de datos y no me funciona alguien sabe que pueda ser esta es la migracion:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace AppWebCursos.Data.Migrations
{
  public partial class MigrationClases : Migration
  {
      protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
       {
         migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "Pago",
            table: "Inscripcion",
            type: "int",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(decimal),
            oldType: "decimal(18,2)");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Nombre",
            table: "Curso",
            type: "nvarchar(50)",
            maxLength: 50,
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: "",
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(max)",
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<bool>(
            name: "Estado",
            table: "Curso",
            type: "bit",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(max)",
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Descripcion",
            table: "Curso",
            type: "nvarchar(max)",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: "",
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(max)",
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
            name: "AsignacionID",
            table: "Curso",
            type: "int",
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "UrlImagen",
            table: "Curso",
            type: "nvarchar(max)",
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Nombre",
            table: "Categoria",
            type: "nvarchar(50)",
            maxLength: 50,
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: "",
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(max)",
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<bool>(
            name: "Estado",
            table: "Categoria",
            type: "bit",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(max)",
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Descripcion",
            table: "Categoria",
            type: "nvarchar(15)",
            maxLength: 15,
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(max)",
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Curso_AsignacionID",
            table: "Curso",
            column: "AsignacionID");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Curso_CategoriaID",
            table: "Curso",
            column: "CategoriaID");

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Curso_Asignacion_AsignacionID",
            table: "Curso",
            column: "AsignacionID",
            principalTable: "Asignacion",
            principalColumn: "AsignacionID",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Curso_Categoria_CategoriaID",
            table: "Curso",
            column: "CategoriaID",
            principalTable: "Categoria",
            principalColumn: "CategoriaID",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Curso_Asignacion_AsignacionID",
            table: "Curso");

        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Curso_Categoria_CategoriaID",
            table: "Curso");

        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "IX_Curso_AsignacionID",
            table: "Curso");

        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "IX_Curso_CategoriaID",
            table: "Curso");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "AsignacionID",
            table: "Curso");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "UrlImagen",
            table: "Curso");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<decimal>(
            name: "Pago",
            table: "Inscripcion",
            type: "decimal(18,2)",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(int),
            oldType: "int");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Nombre",
            table: "Curso",
            type: "nvarchar(max)",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(50)",
            oldMaxLength: 50);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Estado",
            table: "Curso",
            type: "nvarchar(max)",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(bool),
            oldType: "bit");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Descripcion",
            table: "Curso",
            type: "nvarchar(max)",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(max)");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Nombre",
            table: "Categoria",
            type: "nvarchar(max)",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(50)",
            oldMaxLength: 50);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Estado",
            table: "Categoria",
            type: "nvarchar(max)",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(bool),
            oldType: "bit");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Descripcion",
            table: "Categoria",
            type: "nvarchar(max)",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(15)",
            oldMaxLength: 15,
            oldNullable: true);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Tu columna "Estado", de la tabla "Curso", estás cambiando el tipo de dato de nvarchar a bool/bit. Cuando se cambia el tipo de dato de una columna de una tabla, el motor hace una conversión a todos los datos en esa columna. Entity Framework te está diciendo que no puede convertir la cadena *"Activo"* a un valor `*bool*.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!